# Code scribbles are shown in vscode

Tags: linux, linux-mint, visual-studio-code, node.js

[image]

After installing vscode in Linux, I've had this problem. no matter how many times I unistall it  and install again, the problem still recurs. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the font size? Looks like the font is to big. Changing it could reset a user preset thats somewere in regitry.